# Validate collection using sum on a property

Tags: c#, fluentvalidation

I have these 2 entities:

```
public class Parent
{
    public ICollection<Child> Children {get; set;}
}

public class Child
{
    public decimal Percentage {get; set;}
}
```

I would like to add a validation rule so that the total `Percentage` of all children is 100. How can I add this rule in the following validator?

```
public ParentValidator()
{
    RuleFor(x => x.Children).SetCollectionValidator(new ChildValidator());
}

private class ChildValidator : AbstractValidator<Child>
{
    public ChildValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.Percentage).GreaterThan(0));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use predicate validator for collection property:

```
public class ParentValidator : AbstractValidator<Parent> 
{
    public ParentValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.Children)
            .SetCollectionValidator(new ChildValidator())
            .Must(coll => coll.Sum(item => item.Percentage) == 100);
    }
}
```

Comment: SetCollectionValidator is now deprecated. Please refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51968442/how-to-validate-collection-items-using-ruleforeach) for a solution. Something like this should work:


`RuleFor(x => x.Items)
  .Must(coll => coll.Sum(item => item.Percentage) == 100)
  .When(x => x.Items != null);`