# How to validate collection items using RuleForEach

Tags: c#, fluentvalidation

I have been using (successfully) the following validation:

```
RuleFor(x => x.Items)
  .SetCollectionValidator(new ItemValidator())
  .Must(coll => coll.Sum(item => item.Percentage) == 100)
  .When(x => x.Items != null);
```

As the above `SetCollectionValidator` is (will be) deprecated, I changed it to:

```
RuleForEach(x => x.Items)
  .SetValidator(new ItemValidator())
  .Must(coll => coll.Sum(item => item.Percentage) == 100)
  .When(x => x.Items != null);
```

However, `Sum` is not recognized anymore.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use two separate rules. One of them is validate item, and other one is for validation of collection.

```
RuleForEach(x => x.Items)
  .SetValidator(new ItemValidator());

RuleFor(x => x.Items)
  .Must(coll => coll.Sum(item => item.Percentage) == 100)
  .When(x => x.Items != null);
```